# Stuck installing Arch Linux. How should I proceed?

Tags: arch-linux, partition, system-installation, virtualbox, uefi

I am following a tutorial [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Arch-Linux). I'm on step `2.2`. I'm supposed to find out if I have a uefi motherboard by sending the command `efivar -l`. But I don't get the expected output. Instead I get `efivar: error listing variables: Function not implemented     :(`.

Anyway I don't know much about how my motherboard should effect the partitions, but the tutorial insists that it is critical, and I don't want to mess up.

I'm booting from oracle vm virtualbox.

Comment: Please don't follow random tutorials. The Arch Wiki is excellent and there's a very detailed guide [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide). I suggest you follow it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not booted in EFI-mode.
Can you disable Secure Boot -- it could be falling back to "Legacy" mode in the absence of a correctly signed kernel image and bootloader.

And if you have already disabled Secure Boot, this means that you motherboard do not allow UEFI.

The reason why this step is vital is that Legacy boot use MBR and UEFI mostly use ESP. So, it will affect you next step to make your disk parted and install a bootloader.